# gitea ssh refuses to authenticate for one particular pc in the network

Tags: git, docker, ssh, synology, gitea

I've got a docker image of gitea up and running on my Synology NAS, and it has been running fine for some time now. I could fetch, clone, pull and push with no problems. I also have 2 laptops at my home network.

The problem is that one of those laptops suddenly can't fetch the repo over ssh (http works fine). The error is:

```
$ git fetch origin
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I try to `ssh -v` to it, I got bunch of logs and this in between:

```
Hi there, <name>! You've successfully authenticated with the key named <my_mail>, but Gitea does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gitea under another user.
```

It looks like Gitea is accessible, but unable to process the request from this particular PC.

I tried to remove and re-add public auth key in gitea GUI but it didn't help.

I also tried to execute following in Site Administration: `Update the '.ssh/authorized_principals' file with Gitea SSH principals.` and `Update the '.ssh/authorized_keys' file with Gitea SSH keys.` - didn't help, either.

Gitea is NOT using build-in ssh.

This is SSH config part of Gitea configuration:
[image]

What could cause the problem? How can I attempt to fix it?

Comment: the URL specified as remote is `ssh://git@host:13002/dir/repo.git`

Comment: Check the output of `ssh -vvv git@host -p13002`

Comment: Should I look for anything specific? The log is long and it connects succesfully (as far as I can tell) with info `Hi there, <name>! You've successfully authenticated with the key named <my_mail>, but Gitea does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gitea under another user.`, and some more debug lines :I

Comment: The `ssh` output seems to be okay. But then you should check if git uses the same connection with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git fetch`

Comment: Thanks, thats neat! Thanks to this I realized that Pageant is not working and git keeps asking for passphrase, but it does it only when using `ssh -v`. When I remove the env variable it simply failes to connect. Strange!